# Avoid search in middle of word - SOLR

Tags: solr

I am finding some vague behavior while searching. The keyword is searching in middle of the word. For ex:

Indexed items

```
"sample one" 
"jones"
```

and when searched for

```
"sample one"
```

it returns both records which is not required.

Is solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory the concern here ? OR any other

FIELD TYPE

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="25" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

VERBOSE OUTPUT

```
WT

text
raw_bytes
start
end
position
type

Sample
[53 61 6d 70 6c 65]
0
6
1
word

Video
[56 69 64 65 6f]
7
12
2
word

One
[4f 6e 65]
13
16
3
word




ENGTF

text
raw_bytes
start
end
position
type

Samp
[53 61 6d 70]
0
4
1
word

Sampl
[53 61 6d 70 6c]
0
5
2
word

Sample
[53 61 6d 70 6c 65]
0
6
3
word

Vide
[56 69 64 65]
7
11
4
word

Video
[56 69 64 65 6f]
7
12
5
word






LCF

text
raw_bytes
position
start
end
type

samp
[73 61 6d 70]
1
0
4
word

sampl
[73 61 6d 70 6c]
2
0
5
word

sample
[73 61 6d 70 6c 65]
3
0
6
word

vide
[76 69 64 65]
4
7
11
word

video
[76 69 64 65 6f]
5
7
12
word






WT

text
raw_bytes
start
end
position
type

Sample
[53 61 6d 70 6c 65]
0
6
1
word

Video
[56 69 64 65 6f]
7
12
2
word

One
[4f 6e 65]
13
16
3
word




ENGTF

text
raw_bytes
start
end
position
type

Samp
[53 61 6d 70]
0
4
1
word

Sampl
[53 61 6d 70 6c]
0
5
2
word

Sample
[53 61 6d 70 6c 65]
0
6
3
word

Vide
[56 69 64 65]
7
11
4
word

Video
[56 69 64 65 6f]
7
12
5
word






LCF

text
raw_bytes
position
start
end
type

samp
[73 61 6d 70]
1
0
4
word

sampl
[73 61 6d 70 6c]
2
0
5
word

sample
[73 61 6d 70 6c 65]
3
0
6
word

vide
[76 69 64 65]
4
7
11
word

video
[76 69 64 65 6f]
5
7
12
word
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details, like how your field(s) that you are searching are configured, etc. You mentioned EdgeNGramFilterFactory, are you using this and if so, how?

Comment: i have used copy method for searching certain fields. EdgeNGram i used for search like sear searc search... i have edited and added the EdgeNGram field type

Comment: Could you check in Solr admin ? Go to analysis tab, check verbose output and paste your result here

Comment: i have added the verbose output. please check

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right field-type to your problem? You do have a _minGramSize_ of 4 in your EdgeNGramFilterFactory. This means that all tokens (words) that come along this filter and are of length three and smaller, will be thrown away, since minGramSize is 4. So the word _One_ should never show up on the analysis tab. Despite that it is Uppercased in the beginning, whereas the snipped from you schema does have LowerCaseFilterFactory.

Comment: yes, field type "text" is my copy field type, where i copy all the fields to this and search at one shot....Main concern here is why it is searching in middle of the word, You can check the example above

Comment: ideally "jones" shouldn't be searchable... WHEN THERE IS A KEY "One"